# Updating UI after state update in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

EDIT:

I fixed the problem in the reducer...changed this:

```
case ADD_LIST_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        lists: {
          ...state.lists.map(list =>
            list._id === payload.id
              ? { ...list, listItems: payload.data }
              : list
          )
        },
        loading: false
      };
```

to this:

```
case ADD_LIST_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        lists: [
          ...state.lists.map(list =>
            list._id === payload.id
              ? { ...list, listItems: payload.data }
              : list
          )
        ],
        loading: false
      };
```

Stupid error on my part.

---

I have a MERN todo application using redux for state management and useEffect() for UI updates (all functional instead of class-based components). However, when I change state in the redux store, the UI does not update. This seems to only happen during an update triggered by a post request from the front end to the backend, where I pass data to an action, which is handled in a reducer (a js file rather than the useReducer() hook in this app). My backend will update properly, but the UI will crash.

What happens is, I input, say, a new list item in a given todo list, and the error I get is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: list.lists.map is not a function
    at Dashboard (Dashboard.jsx:32)
```

I'm not sure where to use an additional useEffect(), if needed, or if there's a problem in my reducer...here's the relevant flow (removed all className declarations and irrelevant parts):

```
/* Dashboard.jsx */

// imports //


const Dashboard = ({ auth: { user }, list, getLists }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getLists();
  }, [getLists]);

  return (
    <>
      <p>Lists...</p>
      {list.lists &&
        list.lists.map(list => <List key={list._id} list={list} />)}
    </>
  );
};

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  getLists: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  list: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  list: state.list
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getLists })(Dashboard);
```

```
/* List.jsx */

// imports

const List = ({ list, addListItem, getLists }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    getLists();
  }, []);

  const handleAddItem = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addListItem(list._id, { text });
    setText('');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {list.listItems &&
        list.listItems.map((item, index) => (
          <ListItem
            key={index}
            item={item}
            listId={list._id}
            itemIndex={index}
          />
        ))}
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleAddItem}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="text"
            placeholder="add a to-do item"
            value={text}
            onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input type="submit" value="add" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

List.propTypes = {
  addListItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getLists: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(null, {
  addListItem,
  getLists
})(List);
```

```
/* list.actions.js */

// imports

export const addListItem = (listId, text) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await api.post(`/lists/${listId}`, text); // returns all list items after adding new item

    dispatch({
      type: ADD_LIST_ITEM,
      payload: { id: listId, data: res.data }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: LIST_ERROR,
      payload: { message: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

```
/* list.reducer.js */

// imports

const initialState = {
  lists: [],
  list: null,
  loading: true,
  error: {}
};

const list = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_LISTS:
      return { ...state, lists: payload, loading: false };
    case LIST_ERROR:
      return { ...state, error: payload, loading: false };
    case ADD_LIST_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        lists: {
          ...state.lists.map(list =>
            list._id === payload.id
              ? { ...list, listItems: payload.data }
              : list
          )
        },
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default list;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume when creating your app's store, you are passing `list` as rootReducer,

Meaning your app's main state is exactly the state `list` is managing.

So if you need to access property `lists` of the state, you need to do it like this:

```
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  lists: state.lists   /// state in here is exactly the state of list reducer
});
```

Now, in `Dashboard` `lists` is that array that you manipulate in `list` reducer.

Also, you have defined a property also named `list` in `list` reducer. It is initially defined to be null, also in the reducer, you never change it:

```
const initialState = {
  lists: [],
  list: null,  /// none of actions ever change this, meaning it's currently useless.
  loading: true,
  error: {}
};
```